# Create table with concatenating current year and month

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to create a table in Postgresql if it is not already there and insert some data in it.

The table has to have the following name convention which is test_yyyymm where yyyymm is current year and month.

I tried various ways and stopped on dynamic sql.

```
DO
$$
BEGIN
    EXECUTE 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ' || 'select concat(''test_'', (select to_char(now(), ''yyyymm'')))::text'|| ' (temp_id INT NOT NULL,
                temp_name varchar(150),
                PRIMARY KEY (temp_id))';
END;
$$
```

if I make a select with only this part

```
select concat('test_', (select to_char(now(), 'yyyymm')))::text
```

I get the name that I want, but it does not work inside dynamic sql.

I've tried to remove that line and replace it with a static name and it works like a charm, so I am sure that, the problem is in the table name.

```
DO $$
BEGIN
    EXECUTE 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ' || 'test_table' || ' (temp_id INT NOT NULL,
                 temp_name varchar(150),
                 PRIMARY KEY (temp_id))';
END;

$$
```

How can I achieve this in a humane way?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close. `select` isn't needed, just use the conversion as-is.

```
DO $$
BEGIN 
EXECUTE 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ' || concat('Log_',to_char(now(), 'yyyymm')) || ' (temp_id INT NOT NULL,
                temp_name varchar(150),
                PRIMARY KEY (temp_id))';
END;
$$
```